# GA trained NN performs worse on Test Set than BP trained NN

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm, backpropagation

I trained a Neural Network with a GA and with Backpropagation. The GA finds suitable weights for the training data but performs poorly on the test data. If I train the NN with BackPropagation, it performs much better on the test data even though the training error isn't much smaller than for the GA trained version. Even when I use the weights obtained by the GA as initial weights for Backpropagation, the NN performs worse on the test data than using only Backpropagation for training. Can anyone tell me where I could have made a mistake?

Comment: You might have a look at asking the question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ which cover this topic in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read something about overfitting. In short you will be excelent at training set but poor at testing set(because NN follows anomaly and uncertainity and datas). Task of NN is generalize, but GA only perfect minimize error in training set(to be fair, this is GA task).

There are some methods how to deal with overfitting. I suggest you use validation set. First step is division your data into the three sets. Training testing and validation. Method is simple, you will train your NN with GA to minimalize error on training set, **but you also run your NN on validation set**, only run, not train. Error of network decrease on training set, but error should also decrease at validation set. So if error decrease at training set, but start increase at validation set, you must stop with learning(please don't stop at first iterations).

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar problem, and the choice of the initial values of the neural network does not seem to affect the final classification accuracy. I used the feedforwardnet() function in matlab to compare the two cases. One is direct training, and the program gives random initial weights and bias values. One is to find the appropriate initial weights values and bias values through the GA algorithm, and then assign them to the neural network, and then start training. However, the latter approach does not improve the accuracy of neural network classification.